# Wrong core register layout when context switching in uc/os-III

Tags: arm, embedded, context-switch, cortex-a8

uC/OS-III says:

> When calling OSTaskCreate(), uC/OS-III initializes the top of the
>   task's stack with a copy of the CPU register in the same stacking
>   order as if they were all saved at the beginning of
>   an ISR.

Here is the arm Complete ARM register set.

**FYI: I'm using cortex-a8 which is based on v7 architecture, but I believe that v7 core's register layout is the same as following image**
[image: Complete ARM register set]
Here is the debug info before executing OSTaskCreate statement:
[image]
Here is the debug info after executing OSTaskCreate statement:
[image]
It's obvious that these values the stack saves is totally different from core register.

How could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the reference you need, [context switching](https://doc.micrium.com/display/osiiidoc/Context+Switching), indicating that SR/PC are saved first, then the other registers r0-r13. For a definative answer, you can refer to the source in `os_cpu_a.asm`.